# Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'string'

Tags: c#

I'm creating a small program which asks the user to input some information about themselves and then how many hours of work they've done, it then calculates their gross, net pay, and pay after tax. I'm not 100% familiar with all the terms in c# but was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction, also i'd like to know if there were any ways to shorten the code so that it looks cleaner and easier to read and a way to make it so there is only 2 decimal places after the number.

This is just a small part of the code where i was receiving an error.
All of these are floats

hrsworked: user puts in how many hours they've worked
tax: predetermined value which is 35.72%
prate: just the payrate which is $31.31 per hour

```
  Console.WriteLine("\nGross Pay            " + (hrsworked * prate).ToString("c"));
  Console.WriteLine("Tax                    " + ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c"));
  Console.WriteLine("Net Pay                " + ((hrsworked * prate) - ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c")));
```

Comment: Do you remember order of operations in math? Look at your last line, * is evaluated before -.

Comment: `((hrsworked * prate) - ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c"))` - Check your brackets.

Comment: Since you are new to C#, you get a beginner task: In your 3rd code line, count the parentheses and figure out the matching `(`-`)` - then look where do you apply the .ToString() method...

Comment: This is one reason why it's a good idea to pull out subexpressions into variables - especially ones that you are using more than once, like `(hrsworked * prate)`. Calculate that once up front, give it a good name, and then your next lines will be shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: It might be a good idea to learn how to use format strings, `Console.WriteLine("Net Pay                {0}", YourCacluationHere);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some typos in your code. Take some time to carefully review what you're doing.

Take this line for example, which is causing the error in your title:

```
((hrsworked * prate) - ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c")));
```

Here's how the parentheses are grouped:

```
(
    (hrsworked * prate)
    -
    ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c")
)
```

You're trying to subtract a string from a number. You need to adjust your parentheses:

```
... ((hrsworked * prate) - ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100))).ToString("c"));
```

---

As for "cleaner", I'd absolutely follow Blorgbeard's advice and break these out. For example:

```
var grossPay = hrsworked * prate;
var taxPercentage = tax / 100;

... + grossPay.ToString("c"));
... + (grossPay * taxPercentage).ToString("c"));
... + (grossPay - (grossPay * taxPercentage)).ToString("c")));
```

*(Due to order of operations, you don't need the inner-most parentheses on the last line above, but I think it makes it more readable. YMMV)*

Comment: Nice use of parentheses and white space.  Source code is for humans, not just compilers. :)

Comment: can I suggest an afterTaxesPay var?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter hours.");
        var hoursWorked = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter pay rate");
        var payRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter tax.");
        var tax = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        var grossPay=(hoursWorked * payRate);
        var taxAmount = (grossPay * (tax / 100));
        var netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Gross Pay {0}",grossPay.ToString("c")));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Tax {0}", taxAmount.ToString("c")));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Net Pay {0}", netPay.ToString("c")));
```

Comment: While I like the intermediate vars, I would recommend NOT interleaving output and calculation.  Input -> Calculate -> Output.  The source code will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in this part of the code:

`(hrsworked * prate) - ((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c"))`

You try to subtract a string `((hrsworked * prate) * (tax / 100)).ToString("c")`  from `(hrsworked * prate)`

You can try to read about C# in http://www.dotnetperls.com/. I find the examples simple to understand.