# Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'float'

Tags: c#

Im new at c# and i have error CS0019 I dont know how to fix it
i wanna make math program with substract and i wanna make my program logic:
if you pressed button textbox number will substract and show result in text box.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float num = 1
        textBox1.Text - num ;

    }
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense; you don't assign the result of the `textBox1.Text - num` operation anywhere so nothing of interest would happen.

Comment: The issue you're getting stems from the fact that you can't subtract a floating-point number `1` from a string of text. What would you expect to happen in that case? Do you maybe want to parse the text into a number first, then subtract 1 from it?

Comment: You should provide information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like `textBox.Text = float.TryParse(textBox.Text, out var val) ? $"{val - num}" : testBox.Text;` to first parse the text to float, apply the subtraction and then turn it back to a string and set it to the text box or leave it alone if it fails to parse in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049695/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-float-and-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the contents of textBox1. Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num1 = 1;
    double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox1.Text);
    double result = num2 - num1;
    txtBox1.Text = result.ToString(); //Or whatever other text box you want to put this in
}
```

Comment: This is still pointless since you do nothing with the `result`.

Comment: @juharr true, I'm assuming that OP has more logic to apply to it after the fact.

Comment: hi,thanks for answer but can you answer me. How i can show result in text box?